# Network data loss using 4 robots

Tags: ros, transmission, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a group of four robots. Right now I am doing testings on the data transmission over a wireless network, the output of `rqt_graph` is shown below.

[image: image description]

- Robot 1, 2 and 3 are different robots sending a message.
- Leader 1, 2 and 3 are the same leader robot running the listener 3 times.

So, I have 4 robots, 3 sending, 1 receiving. I want my application to be as real time as possible. I am running at 30 Hz. First I tough to put nothing on the stack, so the data I receive is always the newest one, the publishers and subscribers are set with a stack size of 1, but with that I lose a lot of data. The output is shown below:

- `Machine` is the robot sending data
- `Message` is the message number received
- `Counter` is the message number expected

I print out whenever `Message` and `Counter` are different and at every second.

```
[ INFO] [1458884633.094665493]: Machine <0> Message<150>
[ WARN] [1458884633.249164663]: Machine <1> Message<188> Counter <186>
[ WARN] [1458884633.249326863]: Machine <1> Message<192> Counter <189>
[ INFO] [1458884633.261020475]: Machine <2> Message<270>
[ WARN] [1458884633.367932119]: Machine <0> Message<154> Counter <152>
[ WARN] [1458884633.368090775]: Machine <0> Message<158> Counter <155>
[ WARN] [1458884633.619671753]: Machine <1> Message<202> Counter <196>
[ WARN] [1458884633.720845046]: Machine <0> Message<165> Counter <163>
[ WARN] [1458884633.721000330]: Machine <0> Message<168> Counter <166>
[ INFO] [1458884633.832237240]: Machine <1> Message<210>
[ WARN] [1458884633.972283715]: Machine <2> Message<289> Counter <285>
[ WARN] [1458884633.972402930]: Machine <2> Message<291> Counter <290>
[ INFO] [1458884634.102028388]: Machine <0> Message<180>
[ WARN] [1458884634.154272541]: Machine <1> Message<217> Counter <214>
[ WARN] [1458884634.154369931]: Machine <1> Message<219> Counter <218>
[ INFO] [1458884634.262470496]: Machine <2> Message<300>
[ INFO] [1458884634.832749255]: Machine <1> Message<240>
[ WARN] [1458884635.340362798]: Machine <0> Message<215> Counter <209>
[ WARN] [1458884635.340468232]: Machine <0> Message<217> Counter <216>
```

Then, I tried increasing the stack to 10 elements, and the output was improved:

```
[ INFO] [1458885577.781345375]: Machine <0> Message<150>
[ INFO] [1458885578.197521359]: Machine <1> Message<180>
[ INFO] [1458885578.806767762]: Machine <0> Message<180>
[ INFO] [1458885578.973456886]: Machine <2> Message<240>
[ WARN] [1458885578.973578372]: Machine <2> Message<249> Counter <241>
[ INFO] [1458885579.348755549]: Machine <2> Message<270>
[ INFO] [1458885579.417701869]: Machine <1> Message<210>
[ INFO] [1458885579.781167298]: Machine <0> Message<210>
[ WARN] [1458885580.121854098]: Machine <1> Message<222> Counter <218>
[ WARN] [1458885580.121951202]: Machine <1> Message<228> Counter <223>
[ INFO] [1458885580.390034144]: Machine <1> Message<240>
```

If I increase the stack then I start experiencing a lag. I think I will have to do a trade between the speed in the transmission and the stack size to something that suits my application. But, I was wondering if there is a way to improve the network communication? Maybe some settings in ROS or my network that I am not taking into account.

**EDIT 1**

As al_dev suggested, changing to UDP improved the transmission, but now I can't get to work one detail. I am using the MultiThreadedSpinner as shown, it works well:

```
ros::MultiThreadedSpinner multi_spinner( 3 );
multi_spinner.spin();
```

But what I actually want is:

```
ros::CallbackQueue callback_queue;
callback_queue.callOne( ros::WallDuration( 0 ) );
ros::MultiThreadedSpinner multi_spinner( 3 );

while( ros::ok() )
{
    loop_rate.sleep();
    multi_spinner.spin( &callback_queue );
}
```

But when I use this, it never enters the callback. How to use  callOne?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230127/network-data-loss-using-4-robots/) by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2016-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-25**:
Just an FYI: *stack* == *queue*.

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2016-03-28**:
@luis-ruiz, are you using TCPROS or UDPROS here?

**Comment by [Luis Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/14101/luis-ruiz/) on 2016-03-30**:
I am connecting via ssh, so I think I am using TCP. I followed [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For multi-robot systems where you have a crowded network and delayed data becomes quickly irrelevant (e.g sharing position/velocities to neighbors in a swarming formation), UDP can a better choice, at the expense of less reliability.

If leader 1,2,3 are the same robot and run the same listener, you might want to try using a single node with N subscribers and a Multi-threaded spinner instead of the default ros::spin() ( http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning ).

If you really cannot get the performance you want, it might be good to stress test your network without ROS to understand exactly where the bottlenecks are.

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1